# Trigger event on Textinput or Textarea value change MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want add the contents of a textarea (or a textfield) to a reactive variable and bind it to a view, similar to AngularJS double binding.

The problem to listen to `keydown` is that the last character will not be included. If I use `keyup` there will be a delay. Is there a way to listen to value change in a text field and immediately after it changes set the reactive variable?

```
Template.body.events({
     "keydown #textarea":function(){
         input.set( $('#textarea').val());
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `input` event which is probably better suited for what you need.

```
Template.body.events({
  "input #textarea":function(){
    input.set( $('#textarea').val());
  }
});
```